# git cherry-pick being ancestor-aware, not just applying a patch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

It sure would be nice if `merge`-like cleverness and awareness of common ancestors were available in `cherry-pick`. Is that possible?

Suppose we have this situation. We have a development where commits are made to `dev` and are cherry-picked to `release`. [1]

```
X----Y---A1---A2---B---Z   dev
  \
   \----B'                 release

 A1: Remove function foo()
 A2: Re-add function foo() (ooops, it was needed) and change function bar()
     (A1 and A2 are listed together becuase they are two commits, attempts, to fix the same bug.)
 B:  Modify function foo()
 B': B is cherry-picked into the release branch
 X, Y, Z: changes touching unrelated files. No conflicts here.
```

Now we want to cherry-pick `A1` and `A2` into the release branch. Obviously, we cannot just cherry-pick them because
 there will be a conflict on the deletion/modification of `foo()`.

But a smart person could see how A1 and A2 delete and re-add `foo()` and how this can indeed be merged into the `release` branch. And you could even make an algorithm to do it where you take all commits to `dev` that occur after `A1,A2` that are already in `release`, go back to the commit before that, and then re-apply `A1, A2, B` in the order they were applied to `dev` then take that final state of files and put it after B' on the `release` branch. (Because on the `release` branch, no history modification is *ever* allowed.)

And that's all fine and well, but it gets hairy pretty quickly. It sure would be nice if `merge`-like cleverness and awareness of common ancestors were available in `cherry-pick`. Is that possible?

Steve

[1] I know you probably think this is ridiculous. Please don't bother telling me that. Honestly, it is more complicated than you think and there are good reasons for it. I have tried to keep things simple for this question and it's not in anybody's best interest to have a multi-page explanation of why, in this case, this is the right thing to do.

Comment: But the whole difference between `merge` and `cherry-pick` ... the whole reason that `cherry-pick` exists, is to omit changes introduced by ancestors of the picked commit(s).  The thing you want may be reasonable, but it is way more sophisticated than `cherry-pick`s view of the world